# Why is this reasoning to calculate combinations wrong?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

In this [question on choosing 3 balls such that at least 2 are red](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4274025/how-many-ways-can-we-draw-three-balls-such-that-at-least-two-are-red):

There are $\binom{3}{2} $ ways to choose the two red balls. Then there are $\binom{5}{1}$ ways to choose 1 of the remaining balls. Together they make $\binom{3}{2} \times \binom{5}{1} =15$. When you take the red case separately, you get $\binom{3}{2} \times \binom{4}{1} + \binom{3}{3} =13 $

Comment: To see this even more clearly, suppose we change the problem slightly.  Suppose there are only three balls to begin with, all of which are red.  We ask "How many ways can we choose three of these balls such that at least two are red?"  Well... clearly, there is only one way to select three balls, and that one way does satisfy that at least two are red.  According to your broken logic however, you are saying there are $\binom{3}{2}\times\binom{1}{1}=3$ ways to do this...

Answer (score 2):

You are triple-counting the case where 3 red balls are chosen. You are counting it 3 times because each of the three red balls can be the remaining ball.

In other words choosing R1 and R2 and then another ball which happens to be R3 is counted as a different case to choosing R1 and R3 and then another ball which happens to be R2.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative approach:

Let $(x_1, x_2, x_3)$ denote that there were $x_1$ red balls selected without replacement, $x_2$ white balls selected without replacement, and $x_3$ blue balls selected without replacement.

Assuming that balls of the same color are distinguishable, then, in the generic case, the number of ways of selecting balls that correspond to 
$(x_1,x_2,x_3)~$ is $~\displaystyle \binom{3}{x_1} \times \binom{2}{x_2} \times \binom{2}{x_3}.$

Therefore, there are $3$ different ways of selecting at least $2$ red balls, without replacement, from the $7$ balls:

- $(3,0,0).$ 
  Computation is $~\displaystyle \binom{3}{3} \times \binom{2}{0} \times \binom{2}{0}.$
- $(2,1,0)$.
  Computation is $~\displaystyle \binom{3}{2} \times \binom{2}{1} \times \binom{2}{0}.$
- $(2,0,1)$.
  Computation is $~\displaystyle \binom{3}{2} \times \binom{2}{0} \times \binom{2}{1}.$